# Not getting displayed all vlaues

Tags: java, selenium

Not looping through for loop. giving me the correct size but only first value(text) get fetch and displayed on the console, i want to display all the values(texts) on the screen

System.out.println(totalLOB.size());  //Gives correct size, i.e 3

Here is the code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= NoOfDivs; i++)  {
    String measureName = measureNameList.get(i).getText();
    clickOnAllMeasureListOneAfterOther.get(i).click();  

    System.out.println(totalLOB.size());
    for(int j = 0; j <= totalLOB.size(); j++) {
        if(totalLOB.get(j) != null) {
            System.out.println(totalLOB.get(j).getText());
        }
     } 
}
```

The above code displays only the first value(text) on the console.
And throwing the following error message:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3, size3`

Any advice or suggestion is appreciated and needed! Thanks.

Comment: what is the size of `NoOfDivs` ?

Comment: your second `for` loop running one 4th time as well as you have '<=' change it to '<' and try again, there is one less '}'

Comment: Size of NoOFDivs  is 21, with '<' also displaying only first value(text)  yes now running for all 21 rows and displaying only first text.

Comment: it's varies on  iteration it may  have 2 values, on next may be 3 values and wanted to fetch all texts on every iteration..

Comment: Thanks, Pratik your answer has solved my issue but still not displaying all text only first text it's fetching and displaying. Can you suggest something.

Comment: for(int j=0;j<=totalLOB.size();j++) is not getting execute second time.

Comment: takeout the 'if' and try running it again

Comment: Yes, it has works. Thanks. Also worked with by adding  One missinge '}'. Thanks.

Comment: how do i print output of following code in same line?                                                 for(int j=0;j<totalNoOfLOB.size();j++)
          {           
              System.out.println(totalNoOfLOB.get(j).getText());       
          }      
           
       for(int p=2;p<combinedPerformanceOfMeasure.size();p++)
      {
            if(combinedPerformanceOfMeasure.get(p)!=null){
             
               System.out.println("                 " + combinedPerformanceOfMeasure.get(p).getText());
           }

Comment: There are 2 for loops and wanted to print output row wise, I think by adding one more loop, right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int q = 1;
for(int j=0;j<totalNoOfLOB.size();j++) { 
System.out.print(totalNoOfLOB.get(j).getText());
for(int p=q+1;p<combinedPerformanceOfMeasure.size();p++) {
System.out.print(" " + combinedPerformanceOfMeasure.get(p).getText());
break;
}
System.out.print("\n")
q++;
}
```

Comment: Error Occurred  :UnKnownFormatConversionException = '%'.   Second loop will gives all the values with % such as 50%, second loop has to be start with 2 but should display the value of both loops in one row. And showing error on syso statement of second loop. Itsd running fine individually, displaying all values.

Comment: Sorry, but i couldn't understand what are you trying to say. Can you share the error ?

Comment: When using printf for 2nd loop, its giving an error "UnKnownFormatConversionException = '%'. My first loop output is text say Manager', Employee'....and second loop output is with '%' such as 50%, 40% and so on.  Wanted to have an output in one line. Like Manager      50%, In seconds line Employee     40%.  The problem here is second loop has to be start with '2' as first 2 digits are for Yes/No.

Comment: i think need to be run for loop with 2 variables. Actually 5 columns are there on my each popup. And when i see DOM it has created table for each column. so i am getting size column wise but has to be print row wise.

Comment: Its giving the value in next column but the value of second column remain same for all options. Such as Manager     50%, Employee   50%,   Admin 50%.

Comment: Thank you so much it has work as was expecting but not displaying the value of first. because of different logic for first row. But your code worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Now for next 3 columns have to apply same logic, righ!

Comment: To add one more column added 2 lines in your code but giving not proper output.                int q = 1,t =1;
       for(int j=0;j<totalNoOfLOB.size();j++) { 
       System.out.print(totalNoOfLOB.get(j).getText());
       for(int p=q+1;p<combinedPerformanceOfMeasure.size();p++) {
       System.out.print("     " + combinedPerformanceOfMeasure.get(p).getText());
 for(int tl=0+t; tl<thresdhholdsLowerValues.size();tl++)
  System.out.println("      " +thresdhholdsLowerValues.get(tl).getText());
    break;
       }
       System.out.print("\n");
       q++; t++;
       } Please reply.

Comment: what output do you want and what you are getting

Comment: I have total 5  for loops and the value of each iteration wanted to have in column form.  Your 2 for loop code has successfully displayed values in 2 columns. I tried to add one more loop in you code as above but did not work. 3rd for loop is for(int tl=0+t; tl<thresdhholdsLowerValues.size();tl++)  4th for loop is for(int th=0+t; th<thresdhholdsHigherValues.size();th++).

Comment: Lets chat over here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201952/1 or you can start a new question

Comment: i dont think so i have a enough reputation points, i recently joined stack overflow. I start new question with screenshot in 10-15 minutes.

Comment: once i will post it will let you know here in 15-20 minutes.

Comment: Is it possible i do ask you a question here and send you image on your email id? f

Comment: I am happy to help you but contacting specific members is not how this site is intended to work. If you have a question, please post it for everyone to see, browse, and answer. If it is a good question, it will help other people, too. And if you post it for the entire community, other experienced users will answer your question as well, providing even more valuable insight.

Comment: I asked you for screenshot only for security purpose, i can not display here. Any way i am posting as new question without screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Hi i posted new question, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i was not on my desk. My email id is dh.purvi@gmail.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24509173, please check my question and help.